# Derivatives and solving a system of linear ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on finding the general solution of the system in the form $x=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ given $\dfrac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-4 &1\cr
-6 &1
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{x}$.

I thought the answer would just be $c_1 \left[\begin{array}{c}
-4x\cr
-6x
\end{array}\right] + c_2 \left[\begin{array}{c}
x\cr
x
\end{array}\right]$ but this can't be right since I haven't done any work to solve any differential equation. What I don't understand is how to solve this type of differential equation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're supposed to find $x$ as a function of $t$.  That's what it means to solve a differential equation.

Comment: Okay but how do I do that? I understand that this is a system of 1st-order linear ODEs however, I don't know the exact equations I am supposed to solve.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you can have been given such a task without being told how to solve, or at least what an ODE presented in this form means. Don't you have any such information?

Comment: Check this website as well 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Linear_System_Solutions

Comment: Okay so I'm looking at the first part of that textbook. Their example is: $x' = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$ and they claim a solution for this equation is $x(t) = e^{A(t-t_0)}x(t_0)$. Does it follow that, in my example, $A = c_1$ and $B = c_2$ and $x(t) = c_1 \left[\begin{array}{c}
-4x\cr
-6x
\end{array}\right] + c_2 \left[\begin{array}{c}
x\cr
x
\end{array}\right]$ and $u(t) = c_1 \left[\begin{array}{c}
-4x\cr
-6x
\end{array}\right] + c_2 \left[\begin{array}{c}
x\cr
x
\end{array}\right]$?

Comment: see page 142 of http://www.supermath.info/DifferentialEqns.pdf

Comment: For your case $A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{ - 4}&1\\
{ - 6}&1
\end{array}} \right]$. ${e^{At}}$ is called State-transition matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix

Comment: Solution of $\dot x = Ax$ is $x(t) = {e^{At}}x(0)$ so if you compute $e^{At}$ then by knowing the initial condition you know the solution at any time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = (x_1(t),x_2(t))^T$, then the equation can be written as
$$
\frac d{dt} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} =  \pmatrix{-4 & 1\\-6&1} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}
= \pmatrix{-4x_1 + x_2\\-6x_1 + x_2}
$$
So, you're meant to solve the system of equations given by
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1'(t) = -4 x_1(t) + x_2(t)\\
x_2'(t) = -6x_1(t) + x_2(t)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Okay so I already know this much however I am unsure how to solve it. I tried noticing that $x_2 = -4x_1 - x_1' \implies x'_2 = -6x_1 -4x_1 - x_1'$

Comment: *I already know this much*: if that's the case, then what was your "answer" supposed to mean?

Comment: There are two main ways of solving a system like this: either make it into a second order ODE, or using eigenvalues.  Which one are you thinking of?

Comment: Also, if you do *"know this much"*, then you know *"the exact equations you are supposed to solve"*

Comment: I don't understand how to do either. I've spent a lot of time looking at my textbook and listening to my professor's lectures but I don't find them helpful. 

So yes, you're right that I do understand what equations I'm supposed to solve however I do not know how to solve them. I am also unsure which method to use - I understand what a 2nd-order ODE is and what eigenvectors/values are however, again, I do not understand how to set up the solutions.

Comment: Check control text books, under the title of "zero-input solution of LTI systems".

Comment: Section 3 of this book will help you "Pierre R. Belanger, Control Engineering: A Modern Approach"

Comment: @ Reza - While I appreciate your help, I cannot simply just go find this book. Do you have a link that you can provide?

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether I think you'll find [this resource](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsDE.aspx) helpful.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether [solution using eigenvalues:](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealEigenvalues.aspx)

Comment: Check this http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/StateSpaceResponse.pdf

Comment: Okay so I am trying to find the $Det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ and I get the characteristic equation $\lambda^2 + 5\lambda + 2=0$ which implies $\lambda = \dfrac{-5\pm\sqrt{18}}{2}$ which is extremely messy. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use the D-Operator Method which is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
(D+4) &-1 \\ 
 (6)& (D-1)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Multiply the second row by $(D+4)$ and divide by 6 to get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
(D+4) &-1 \\ 
 (D+4)& \frac{(D-1)(D+4)}{6}
\end{bmatrix}$$

now subtract the second from one

$$(\frac{(D-1)(D+4)}{6}+1)x_2=0$$
this means
$$[(D-1)(D+4)]x_2+6x_2=0$$
$$[D^2+3D-4]x_2+6x_2=0$$
$$x''_2+3x'_2-4x_2+6x_2=0$$
$$x''_2+3x'_2+2x_2=0$$

the solution is 
$$x_2=C_1e^{-1t}+C_2e^{-2t}$$

Comment: I have never heard of the D-operator method before nor am I expected to know this for my class. Thank you nonetheless for your answer.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether you r welcome